# sub string according to some sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, string, substring

Q:

I want to get sub strings according to some sign like `-` .

EX:

if i have string like this :

```
saturday-sa-0-
```

and i wanna to get:

```
saturday

sa

0
```

I search and find the following method:

```
string substring = name.Split('-')[i];
```

---

my code block sample:

```
foreach (string name in q)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        string substring = name.Split('-')[i];
                    }
                }
```

but i read the comments about the performance drawbacks when i have a long string ..
my question is: Is there any way to substring according to specific `sign` and not affect badly on the performance code?

Comment: Are you anticipating performance issues you may never have?string.Split() would be the way to go unless you have a specific performance issue that you have tracked down to being caused by using string.split();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should execute the Split operation only once. I.e., instead of

```
some loop {
    ...
    string substring = name.Split('-')[i];
    ...
}
```

use

```
string[] substrings = name.Split('-');
some loop {
    ...
    string substring = substrings[i];
    ...
}
```

Second, don't worry about the performance of Strint.Split too much unless

- you have a real, measurable performance problem and
- you know that String.Split is the culprit.

For example, if you have some database operation that takes 1 second, it does not really matter if the subsequent Split operation takes 0.001 or 0.002 seconds.

---

**EDIT**: Regarding the code in your comment: You can refactor

```
foreach (string name in q) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       string substring = name.Split('-')[i]; 
       // do something with substring
    }
}
```

to

```
foreach (string name in q) {
    string[] substrings = name.Split('-'); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       string substring = substrings[i]; 
       // do something with substring
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach (string name in q)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        string substring = name.Split('-')[i];
                    }
                }`

Comment: please edit `string substrings = name.Split('-');` to `string []substrings = name.Split('-');`thanks

Answer (score 3):

Splitting a string is `O(N)` , no more and no less, which is the actual complexity of `String.Split` So even if you write your own procedure, it cannot be REALLY faster. Perhaps it can be slightly faster. In any case, first make sure that the performance of `String.Split` is indeed insatisfactory for you.

And yes, if you split is over and over in a LOOP, then it will be a performance issue. You must first split it and then iterate over the array - see other answers

Answer (score 2):

The issues with split are if it is over used.  If you need to split a string on a character then split the string.  Regex is the next most used way but comes with its own set or performance gotchas.  If you really need to keep you foot print small scanning the string and doing your processing in place is you best option, however this is fraught with peril as well since .net string are immutable and you may well run it the same issues you run into with split.  So I guess the long and the short of it is use split and if that doesn't meet your need reevaluate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on your data. However, you should not repeatedly do ...

```
string substring = name.Split('-')[i];
```

... since this will split your string into parts every time you need to access just one of the parts. Instead, cache the split result like this ...

```
string[] parts = name.Split('-');
```

... and then use ...

```
string substring = parts[i];
```

... to access the respective parts.

Comment: Whats the diff between string substring = name.Split('-')[i]; and string[] parts = name.Split('-')[i]; as per your answer?